# GitHub Action Workflow throws error: ${ GITHUB_SHA }: bad substitution

Tags: github, github-actions

In my deployment workflow I want to pack my artifacts into a tar file. I would like to use the github_sha hash as the name. I have written the following line for this:

```
- name: Create deployment artificact with ${{ github.sha }} as Commit-Hash
  env:
    GITHUB_SHA: ${{ github.sha }}
  run: tar vcfz "${ GITHUB_SHA }".tar.gz --exclude=*.git --exclude=node_modules --exclude=tests *
```

Unfortunately, the dynamic name doesn't quite work. If I choose a static name like `app.tar.gz` it would work. I get this error message:

```
0s
Run tar vcfz "${ GITHUB_SHA }".tar.gz --exclude=*.git --exclude=node_modules --exclude=tests *
  tar vcfz "${ GITHUB_SHA }".tar.gz --exclude=*.git --exclude=node_modules --exclude=tests *
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    GITHUB_SHA: 134e1d9adb515cfe908866092a37aa0880ada128
/home/runner/work/_temp/32bf4668-1034-4849-9eab-b789d201b43f.sh: line 1: ${ GITHUB_SHA }: bad substitution
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

**Question**

How can I create the name for the tar file dynamically? What do I have to change to make it work?

Comment: In shell/Bash, `${GITHUB_SHA}` or `$GITHUB_SHA` should work fine. The surroundings spaces seem to be the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to pass the variable into the tar command without quotes. So: `run: tar vcfz ${{ github.sha }}.tar.gz ...`

```
#dont work
run: tar vcfz "${ GITHUB_SHA }".tar.gz --exclude=*.git --exclude=node_modules --exclude=tests *

#works
run: tar vcfz ${{ github.sha }}.tar.gz --exclude=*.git --exclude=node_modules --exclude=tests *
```